# how to get the current URL in fbjs?

Tags: javascript, facebook, url, fbjs

I want to get the current URL in fbjs. I have used this

```
window.location
```

However, this doesnt work.

Can anyone please help me ? Thanks.

-
ahsan

Comment: I don't know when window.location wouldn't work. What URL are you trying to get exactly?

Comment: It looks like Facebook's borked JS doesn't allow you to get the current location (although it does allow you to set it).  Maybe somebody knows a workaround, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, heres how I solved it :

Using PHP, we can get the page id and the app id.

Using FQL, we can get the page title.

Using these 3 values we can recreate the current URL (I am working on a fanpage tab)

Hope this helps :)

-
ahsan